# Display number of images actually posted

Tags: images

I'm currently using this PHP code to pull the number of images from a post.

```
$attachments = get_children(array('post_parent'=>$post_array[0]['ID']));
$image_count = count($attachments);
```

It is currently pulling any image that is "attached" to the post, however I would like for it to pull the actual number of images that were used in the post.  How would I display the number of images actually displayed in the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
$image_count = substr_count( $post_array[0]['post_content'], '<img');
```

It won't cover images in galleries ... but you can count IDs in gallery shortcode.

Comment: I don't use galleries anyway.  Perfect!